# Form with different kind of action="link"

Tags: php, html

it is alright if all the inputs/subjects are being in one form?

i dont know how to do it but all i want to do is when i finish entering some grades i will just choose whether i submit is as first quarter,2nd quarter 3rd quarter or 4th quarter.

```
  <form action.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="english">
      <input type="text" name="Math">
      <input type="text" name="Science">
      <input type="text" name="History">

        <a href="1st_quarter.php">1st quarter </a>
        <a href="2nd_quarter.php">2nd quarter </a>
        <a href="3rd_quarter.php">3rd quarter </a>
        <a href="4th_quarter.php">4th quarter </a>
 </form>
```

Comment: Use a radio input and select the quarter when submitting. You shouldn't have 4 files for this. Also should be `action="action.php"`

Comment: `<form action.php"` is another typo. Why not start reading up on forms http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php --- http://myphpform.com/php-form-tutorial.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use this http://codepen.io/CookieMonsta/pen/xgYaLa and add some php to send the info somewhere. ex:email, sheets,...

```
  <form action="action.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="english">
  <input type="text" name="Math">
  <input type="text" name="Science">
  <input type="text" name="History">

  <input type="submit" name="button_1" value="First">
  <input type="submit" name="button_1" value="Second">
  <input type="submit" name="button_1" value="Third">
  <input type="submit" name="button_1" value="Fourth">                                                     
 </form>
```